# Add button on MKMapView in IOS 8

Tags: ios, mkmapview

While I put a image button on mapview it's looks OK on layout screen, but when I run program on simulator or device, the button just disappear? even I use **bringSubviewToFront** still don't work.
is anyone know why?

=================================
[image]

[image]

Comment: OK, I find the solution:
I select the MKMapView and go **Editor > Arrange > Send To Back.**

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue when working with google maps views. The reason was, in my case, I was setting `self.view` to the map view in `viewDidLoad` and since the map took up the whole screen, it would essentially cover up all the widgets in the view controller in my storyboard. To fix this, I used the `addSubview` method to add the button to my map view in `viewDidLoad` like so,

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    // create map view and set to a variable called mapView
    // ...
    self.view = mapView;
    self.view.addSubview(nameOfButton);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the constraints but your constraints is not working properly. Please add the constraints again. I have also attached the screen shot of constraints in below. Which constraints you need to add on button.

[image]

I hope it's helpful for you.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Its working fine with me. i tried it....
It might be because of **constraints** that you applied....
Try it after removing all constraints.

Thanks..

after applying it, if you will get problem then comment.